# Get information of text message received in android 6.0.1 Marshmallow API: 23

Tags: android-6.0-marshmallow

I want to get information from the text message received. Information like Body of text sender's phone number etc. I am trying to do it with the code below. I have permissions in the Manifest.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    //---get the SMS message passed in---
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    String str = "";
    if (bundle != null)
    {
        //---retrieve the SMS message received---
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
        for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
            str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
            str += " :";
            str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            str += "n";
        }
        //---display the new SMS message---
        Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

It works. But not on Marshmallow 6.0.1 API:23. Also, SmsMessage, createFromPdu and getMessageBody all of them are deprecated. I can not find a way to do it in Marshmallow. Please, give me the solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
BroadcastReceiver smsReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
            if(Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())){
                Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();           //---get the SMS message passed in---
                SmsMessage[] msgs;
                String sender;
                if (bundle != null){
                    //---retrieve the SMS message received---
                    try{
                        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                        for(int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                            sender = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                            String messageBody = msgs[i].getMessageBody();
                            // do things here
                            }
                        }
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        Log.d("Exception caught",e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            if (Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                for (SmsMessage smsMessage : Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent)) {
                    String messageBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody();
                    String sender = smsMessage.getOriginatingAddress();
                    // do things here
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Dont forget to register receiver. OnCreate:

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION);
    intentFilter.setPriority(990);
    registerReceiver(smsReceiver, intentFilter);
```

And also unregister.

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(smsReceiver);
    threadTimer.interrupt();
}
```

Comment: Oh sorry. I forgot that. I don't sure but maybe you need to check permission programmatically whether it is in manifest. New android versions want this. For example I tried to write external storage. I had permission in manifest but it was throws exception while writing external storage. Than I checked permission programmatically and problem was solved. Maybe it is same for sms. I have Android 5.0 device. I can't test it now.